# Convert column names to string in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, types

Can somebody explain how this works?
df.columns = list(map(str, df.columns))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not the best way to convert column names to string, use instead:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
```

Your code:

```
df.columns = list(map(str, df.columns))
```

is equivalent to:

```
df.columns = [str(col) for col in df.columns]
```

`map`: for each item in `df.columns` (iterable), apply the function `str` on it but the `map` function returns an iterator, so you need to explicitly execute `list` to generate the list.